# A term for when a computer process exceeds allocated memory by OS

Tags: memory, terminology

What is the term for when a computer process uses too much memory, and the OS has to terminate it? I was thinking `memory leak`, but that implies there is memory not being used that is taken up, which is not the case. I wouldn't use the term `stack overflow` either, because it is possible for the memory to be allocated on the heap.

Comment: Don't forget `segmentation fault` when a process tries to access memory that it is not allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when a computer process uses too much memory, and the OS has to terminate it

What you describe here doesn't happen. The behavior differ from OS to OS, but none happens as you describe it. On Windows for example a memory allocation may fail, but that does not imply the OS terminating the process. The call to allocate memory returns an error code and the process decides how it handles the situation. Linux has this crazy memory allocation scheme on which allocation succeeds without any backing, and then actual reference to the memory may fail. In this case Linux runs the [oom-killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer):

> It is the job of the linux 'oom killer' to sacrifice one or more processes in order to free up memory for the system when all else fails.

Note that the oom-killer a process chosen by the `badness()` function, not necessarily the process that actually touched a page that had no backing (ie. not the process that requested the memory). In Linux is also important to distinguish between the memory being 'allocated' and the memory being 'referenced' the first time (ie. the [PTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) shenanigans).

So, strictly speaking, what you describe doesn't exists. However, the common name for a process 'running out of memory' is `out of memory`, commonly abbreviated as OOM. In most modern systems OOM condition manifests itself as an exception, and is an exception raised voluntarily by the process, not by OS.

One situation when an OS kills a process on-the-spot is when an OOM occurs during a guard-page PTE miss (ie. the OS cannot commit the virtual page). As the OS has no room to actually allocate the guard-page, it has no room to actually write the exception record for the process and it cannot raise the exception (that would a a stack overflow exception, since we're talking about a guard page). Th OS has no choice but to obliterate the process (technically is not a kill, since a kill is a type of signal).

Answer (score 1):

Neither "memory leak" nor "stack overflow" cuts it, really.  A memory leak is a bug in a program that *could* result in running out of memory in the long run. A "stack overflow" is an exhaustion of the call stack.

Not all systems terminate processes that uses up all memory. It is usually the process itself that fails to allocate more memory (within the constraints set by the system), causing an "out of memory" error to occur (in C on Unix, `malloc()` returns a `NULL` pointer and the `errno` variable is set to `ENOMEM`). This does not necessarily occur when a single process is hogging *all* memory, but could happen to any process when lots of memory is used by many other processes (using sloppy language, there might be system-imposed limits on a per-user basis etc.)

I would probably call the process that grabs a huge proportion of the memory on a system a "memory hog", but I have never seen a term describing the *event* of running out of memory. "Memory exhaustion" maybe, or simply "causing an out of memory situation".

Answer (score 0):

OutOfMemory-Exceptions is my best guess

Comment: It's not an answer for this particular question